# Is there any timeout period for NSData datawithcontentsofurl?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timeout, nsdata

Is there any timeout period for NSData datawithcontentsofurl?

Answer (score 7):

dataWithContentsOfURL may have an internal timeout but you want to use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) instead, which allows for asynchronous communication. It also lets you specify a timeout interval.